# Git Hooks: Need to change a string when you merge with master

Tags: git, github, githooks

I am trying to make a git hook that will be called before the git merge that will change some strings in my code. This is so I can have a development branch that is solely development and my master branch to resemble production. I was thinking a post-merge script could be used, check to see if the merge was into master and then do the changes. Otherwise it wouldn't do a thing. What is the best idea?

Edit: I need a way to change some strings in a file that git knows about. So in a file foo.txt I want to change line 4 to be a different string.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want , but git branch --no-merged  will show what branches are not merged.

Comment: What problem do you want to solve? It sounds like you want to not commit a hardcoded password or some other sensitive information. If this is the case then there is a an easy solution for it and it doesn't involve git hooks or other wizardry.

Answer (score 0):

I might use pre merge script, before me merging my development branch into master I can suffix Development, major bug, patch before merge to master. If you automated the release notes it ll fetch all the info and easy to follow what went to the release.